# Cannot register for remote notification

Tags: xcode, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

I know this topic has already been discussed over here, but I still cannot figure out what is going wrong.

I try to register for remote notification, but I cannot get any successful response as much as I get an error...

Here are a couple of images I hope may explain the situation better than a lot of lines.

**1) I enabled the option in my project:**
[image]

**2) The provisioning profile (development mode) seems to be correct**
[image]
[image]

**3) I try to register in my appDelegate (didFinishing method) and then to trace back the results**
[image]

What is strange is the fact that I don't get any NSLog message when running on my device (when using the simulator I get a "cannot get notification on simulator" which I understand very well).

The only lead I have is that there may be something wrong with the profiles since in my Apple portal I have both a developement and a distribution profile. I did not download them but I leave Xcode the ability to upload them. But I would expect to get at least a success or a failure. It looks like here as if the procedure was lost in between, like floating in the cloudy apple sky...

Could anyone help me?

Comment: There's a lot more to push notifications than you show in your post.  You'll need development and production APNS (Apple Push Notification Service) certificates, as well as making different calls to register for the APNS.  I suggest going through this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial

Comment: I read the tutorial actually and I did all the stuff with certificates. The problem was that I forgot to register for NSUserNotificationSettings in the appDelegate just before the "registerForRemoteNotification". But it's fixed now. Thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: But what is strange is that I cannot get more than one valid device token. When testing with "easy APNs Provider" to send push notifications, I can only send to one device. When I try to send to another device, I got a message (invalid token, connection, etc) despite having allowed push notification and getting a token from the delegate method. Would you have any idea?

Comment: Not sure.  I would post it as a separate question specifically around the tokens